# How do I get all radio button id's via the name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have all the id's of the radio buttons with the same name

I've tried using this

```
<input type="radio" name="user" id="Jason" value="Jason11">
<input type="radio" name="user" id="Adam"  value="Adam11">
```

```
var names= $('input[type=radio][name="user"]').attr('id')
console.log(names)
```

but this only shows the first id

Is there a way to show both id's?

Comment: quickly search on google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944559/input-attributes-that-can-have-the-same-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**each()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) iteration.

```js
var names = [];
$('input[type=radio][name=user]').each(function(i, elm) {
     names.push($(elm).prop('id'))
})
console.log(names)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="user" id="Jason" value="Jason11">
<input type="radio" name="user" id="Adam"  value="Adam11">
```

**Update:**

As per your comment if you want to get the nth element's ID then can use `eq(n - 1)` function. Example code for getting second element's ID:

```
var name = $('input[type=radio][name=user]:eq(1)').prop('id')
console.log(name);
```

Comment: then use `eq()`. `var name = $('input[type=radio][name=user]:eq(1)').prop('id')
    console.log(name);`

Comment: Your note about names doesn't make sense for radios. They have same name for a reason

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to create an array

```js
var names = $('input[type=radio][name="user"]').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();

console.log(names)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="user" id="Jason" value="Jason11">
<input type="radio" name="user" id="Adam" value="Adam11">
```

Comment: How do I access the second id?

Comment: What exactly is your use case?

Comment: Nevermind I already fixed it, it was a simple mistake at my end. Thanks for your answer!